# Cocos2d JS / Cocos Creator add touch listener to specific node

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I want to drag a specific sprite on touch. I wonder if I can add event listeners only to a specific node, so I dont have to check which node was touched before starting the specific dragging function for each node. The following code does also "fire" when touched outside of the specific node.

```
this.directionDial = new cc.Node()
    this.directionDial.graphics = this.directionDial.addComponent(cc.Graphics)
    this.node.addChild(this.directionDial)
this.directionDial.graphics.lineWidth = 2;
    this.directionDial.graphics.strokeColor = cc.Color.RED;
    this.directionDial.graphics.circle(80, 0, 10);
    this.directionDial.graphics.stroke();

    var _this = this;

    // Touch control 
    cc.eventManager.addListener({
        event: cc.EventListener.TOUCH_ONE_BY_ONE,
        swallowTouches: true,
        onTouchBegan: function (touch, event) {
            //do something
            _this.forceDirection = 1;
            _this.displayDirection()
            return true;
        }
    }, this.directionDial);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using Cocos Creator you can do something like:

```
this.node.on(cc.Node.EventType.TOUCH_START, this.methodToBeCalled, this);
```